# What is happening with the pointers in this snippet?

Tags: c, pointers

I am curious as to why this is an error and what the error message means. Here is some code:

```
int *x[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
int *y[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};

x = y;
```

I try to compile and I get this:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[3]’ from type ‘char **’
```

Question #1 why is this an error? and Question #2 why are the types different?

Comment: Why are you storing character strings in arrays that hold integer pointers?

Comment: Did you check the line number?

Answer (score 5):

As written, there are quite a few problems. First, the array literals are of type `char*[]`, while `x` and `y` are of type `int*[]`. Second, you can't assign arrays directly, as they are in effect constant pointers.

Comment: I really wish this meme would die.  Arrays aren't constant pointers - they aren't any kind of pointer, they're arrays (a non-empty contiguous sequence of objects of the same type).

Comment: A variable whose type is an array in C follows semantics very similar to constant pointers. It's the same deal with gravity - sure, it's not really constant across the globe, and it's not really a downward force. Nonetheless, it's useful to consider both of those aspects true for the vast majority of uses.

Answer (score 3):

There is an incompatible types error because you are assigning arrays of strings (type char * in C) to arrays of pointers to ints (such as `int *x[]`).  The error message given by the compiler is a little confusing because C does a lot behind the scenes to try to convert variables from one type to another.

As chars are represented internally as numbers (letters correspond to their ASCII values), C is able to convert characters to ints, so it attempts to treat variables x and y as arrays of pointers to chars instead of ints, hence the `char *[3]`.  It sees {"foo", "bar", "baz"} as type `char **` because strings are type `char *` and arrays essentially stored as pointers in C, so it is a pointer to `char *`, or `char **`.

While this doesn't completely relate to your question, I also wonder what you're trying to do with `x = y;`  As it is written, that will make x point to the same array as y, leaving the array that x used to point to inaccessible.  To check whether two variables in C are equal, you would use the == operator.  Testing equality isn't as simple for arrays or strings, but that's completely outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is an error, because an array is a non-modifiable lvalue - meaning you can't assign directly to it.  You can only modify the array's members individually.

The types are different because if an array is used in a context where an lvalue is not required, it is evaluated to a pointer to its first element (`somearray` becomes effectively `&somearray[0]`).

Since the array `y` is used in such a context, it is evaluated as the address of its first element, which has type `int **`.  Since the array `x` *is* in an lvalue context, it is evaluated as an array (`int *[3]`).  (Your error message doesn't actually match your code - I suspect your arrrays are actually arrays of `char *`).

("lvalue context" means, pretty much, one of: The left hand side of an assignment operator (which is where the name comes from); the subject of the `sizeof` operator; or the subject of the `&` operator).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with a good tutorial on pointers and arrays. It looks like you might be coming from an interpreted language like JavaScript or PHP. Things are quite different in C, and you need to get a handle on the notions of stack memory, heap memory, pointers, etc. Once you do this will all make sense and you will be loving C.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason I can't use the same account which I published the question with.

The "int" thing was a typo on my part I really meant it to be "char". Sorry, for the confusion.

However, I think caf answered my question.

"It is an error, because an array is a non-modifiable lvalue - meaning you can't assign directly to it. You can only modify the array's members individually."

I'm am just trying to understand how pointers work in c that's why I am trying these random things you probably normally wouldn't do. I thought this might work since I thought arrays = pointers so I could just make x point to y. I guess not?

Thanks for all your response guys.